# How to get POST data using Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to POST simple data using AJAX. My HTML code is

```
<input type="text" value="myvalue" id="sweet" name="sweet">
<button type="submit" id="mybtn-1">
```

My JQuery code is

```
$('#mybtn-1').click(function(){

   var newSweet = $('#sweet').val();
   if($.trim(newSweet) !== '')
   {
    $.ajax({
        url:"../test_chat.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{sweet:newSweet},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
            $('#test_wrap').load("../test_chat.php").fadeIn("slow");
            alert('Success');
        }
    });
   }
});
```

And my test_chat.php code is

```
<?php 
    echo $_POST["sweet"];
    echo 'hello';
?>
```

I want to echo the POST data in a div with the name "test_wrap". The problem is after clicking the button, I can only echo "hello" on the page.

I know it's happening because the load function is reloading the PHP file but I am looking for a solution so that I can show the POST data on my page.

Comment: Just to add one more thing. #mybtn-1 and #test_wrap both are on same page

Comment: `.load()` makes a separate GET request. You already have the response data from your POST request in `data` so just use `$("#test_wrap").html(data).fadeIn("slow")`

Answer (score 1):

You could return the data directly from your `test_chat.php` file after the post request, no need for double request here, return data like :

```php
<?php 
    echo $_POST["sweet"];
    echo 'hello';
?>
```

Then append it to the div `#test_wrap` like :

```js
$('#mybtn-1').click(function(){
    var newSweet = $('#sweet').val();

    if($.trim(newSweet) !== ''){
        $.ajax({
            url:"../test_chat.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{sweet:newSweet},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $('#test_wrap').html(data).fadeIn("slow");

                alert('Success');
            }
        });
   }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: #mybtn-1 and #test_wrap both are on same page.

Comment: its only giving me success alert

Comment: Try to add `console.log(data)` before the alert and see what it will show.

Comment: You still need to `echo` from PHP for the text to be in the response. `return` does nothing here. I've fixed your answer up since this is the only one that seemed to understand the problem

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to echo it with PHP, you can display it directly from the jQuery success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../test_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data:{
        sweet: newSweet
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#test_wrap').load("../test_chat.php").fadeIn("slow");

        if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
            alert('Success');

            // Here "data" is whatever is returned from your POST
            $("#some_content").html(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

do ajax request of this way in js file:

```
$.ajax({
            data: {keys: values}/*keys you need to post (sweet: newsweet)*/
            , type: 'post'
            , dataType: 'json'
            , url: './php/someFile.php'
            , error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                console.log(jqXHR, status, err);
            }
            , success: function (response) {
                /*use response to innerHTML into a div here*/
            }
        });
```

use echo json_encode in php:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($_POST["sweet"] /*or some value from function in php*/);/*of this way, you can return a response 
    from server to client, echo just print something, but does not return...*/
?>
```